# measurable function and inverse image not measurable set.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

A doubt. 
Exists a $f:X\to Y$ measurable function and $f^{-1}(B)$ is not measurable set for some $B\subset Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f=\mathrm{Id}_X : X \to X$. Then for $B \subset X$ not mesurable, $f^{-1}(B)$ is not mesurable.

Comment: Oh! thanks!
If $f^{-1}(B) $ would be measurable then $(f^{-1})^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$ is measurable because $f^{-1}$ is measurable function, then $(f^{-1})^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))=B $is measurable  a contradiction!